# MOSFET Labeling 2/1 4/1 16/1

Tags: digital-logic, mosfet

[image]

1. What do the 2/1 4/1 16/1 labelings mean?
2. What would you search on google to find the answer? I've tried searching
   mosfet diagramming labeling 4/1 16/1
   MOSFET diagramming

Origin of pic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=317&v=9AyLv4_e_24

Answer (score 4):

It's possibly channel width to channel length: -

[image]

Here's apossibly a simpler view: -

[image]

And this might be a fairly informative image: -

[image]

I meant to add that I searched for "W/L ratio MOSFET" and also [**this**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwj107CP8-3JAhVEXhQKHW7mDSAQFggrMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ee.columbia.edu%2F~bbathula%2Fcourses%2FSSDT%2Flect13.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFOOIjKOTNwU3reAx9zagb6MyMZOg&sig2=B4z0LmMqPtuuU5WnSv8e8A&cad=rja) document might prove useful reading because it covers the W/L ratio in both the ohmic region and the saturation region.

Comment: It IS width / length. Sometimes in arbitrary units w.r.t the minimum size possible in a given technology.